# AngularFire2 v5 Firestore - How to hook up the error callback on "onSnapshot"

Tags: angularfire2

So basically the onSnapshot handler on a Firestore document/collection reference is:

```
ref.onSnapshot(query => {}, error => {}, complete => {})
```

I don't see how it's hooked up in AF2. The Firestore docs stresses that one must handle the various errors that occur in that callback.

Does it simply translate to the equivalent in RxJS land:

```
this.afDb.collection('my_collection')
   .valueChanges()
   .retry();
```

Seeing as my Angular 5 services are singletons, I'd prefer if their active data listeners (Observables) didn't err out due to errors while in beta. Thats the main concern.

Answer (score 2):

To implement retry you need to catch and then throw the error.

```
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(afs: AngularFirestore) {
    afs.doc<{}>('items/three')
      .snapshotChanges()
      .map(action => action.payload.data())
      .catch(e => Observable.throw(e))
      .retry(2)
      .subscribe(
        snap => console.log(snap),
        err => console.log(err, 'Retried a few times')
      );
  }
}
```

In the example above I try to listen to a non-existent document at `items/three`. Calling `.data()` before calling `.exists()` on a non-existent `DocumentSnapshot` will throw an error. I `.catch()` and then throw the error. Using `.retry(2)`, RxJS will try it two more times before calling the error callback in the `.subscribe()` method.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you even need to catch - rethrow? The retry should catch the error in the first place right?